# Windows 7 superbar window preview problem

Tags: windows-7, aero, superbar

When I point at any currently running software on the super-bar for a preview it lasts for less than 2 seconds, hence I cannot point or preview any software. It worked perfectly till i decided that I wanted a change of theme and then Aero stopped working so I troubleshooted for the error and then windows solved the error in the troubleshooting wizard, but the preview was limited to 2 seconds which is very little time or preview or switch running software's.

Is there a way to manually increase the preview time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a delay for the "preview time", it will fade out when the cursor is not over it, The 2 seconds are  maybe the refresh rate, and something goes wrong when a change happen in the preview panel.

so, go to **Performence Options** >>**Visual Effects** and uncheck "animations in the task bar and start menu", see if you can get some results.